# Why can't I find an input element with a placeholder in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

In a webpage I have the following element:

```
<input placeholder="Search in your collabs" class="md-input" type="text">
```

which I try to select by the following piece of code (in `python`):

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']")
```

but when running the code I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']
```

The element I am looking for is inside an iframe which I selected before correctly (I did another `find_element_by_xpath` before that with some other attributes). In detail, what I did before was:

```
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id("clb-iframe-workspace"));
```

So but why is this not working now?

Comment: Share how you switched to `iframe`

Comment: See the command I used to switch to the `iframe`

Comment: `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']`

Comment: its issue with switching the frame your xpath is absolutely fine.Check the locator for frame

Comment: What do you mean by 'locator for frame'?

Comment: I solved it: It was - again - a timing issue. A simple 'sleep' solved the problem...

Answer (score 7):

Using `sleep` (as menitioned in your comment) is a bad solution because it inevitably slows down your test execution and might fail from day to day. A better solution is using timeouts. A timeout waits **up to** a specified time span but continues **as soon as possible** (i.e. your expected condition is fulfilled).

You should either increase your **implicit wait** timeout for locating elements or use an **explicit wait** like e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
....
//wait up to 120sec, poll every sec
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 120, 1).until(
        expect.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search in your collabs']")))
```

as explained [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)